# Repeated datetime index pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with multiple datetime index like

[image]

I would like to split data_value_index into three columns with the same index. So far I have only separated the dataframe and merge it like

```
df1= df[df['data_value_index']==5]
df2= df[df['data_value_index']==9]
df3 = df[df['data_value_index']==14]
df=pd.merge(df1,df2,left_index=True,right_index=True)
```

Is there any simpler way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you need `cumcount` for new key , then `unstack`

```
df.set_index(df.groupby(df.index).cumcount(),append=True)['data_value_index'].unstack()
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit the sequence. It does not look obvious to me!

Comment: @JPV  for mutiple index, you need additional key to distinguish them , that is why groupby and cumcount , it is return the count number of the duplicated value,  when we combine the count value + the value themselves, it became unique row